# На чем можно сделать подобную masonry layout разметку, на flex или js плагином?

Tags: javascript, css, flexbox

на чем можно сделать подобную masonry layout разметку,на fleх или есть какие-то js плагины, да так чтобы потом динамически через ajax без проблем в любое место можно было добавить (вывести) новый блок (блоки)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: https://packery.metafizzy.co/

Comment: + https://github.com/desandro/masonry/issues/374 моей предыдущей ссылке :)

Answer (score 2):

Я не уверен в том что минусовать margin хорошая практика но как пример можно рассматривать..

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.parent {
  display: flex;
}

.block:first-child {
  width: 50%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 4px;
}

.item-1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background: #cc11dd;
  border: 4px solid #fff;
}

.item-2 {
  width: 50%;
  height: 200px;
  background: #11ff66;
  border: 4px solid #fff;
}

.block:nth-child(2) {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: flex-start;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 4px;
}

.item-block {
  width: 50%;
  border: 4px solid #fff;
}

.item-block:nth-child(1) {
  background: lightblue;
  height: 220px;
}

.item-block:nth-child(2) {
  background: lightgreen;
  height: 180px;
}

.item-block:nth-child(3) {
  background: yellow;
  height: 200px;
}

.item-block:nth-child(4) {
  background: pink;
  height: 150px;
  margin-top: -36px;
}

.item-block:nth-child(5) {
  background: gold;
  height: 190px;
}

.item-block:nth-child(6) {
  background: #ccc;
  height: 190px;
  margin-top: -80px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="block">
    <div class="item-1"></div>
    <div class="item-2"></div>
    <div class="item-2"></div>
    <div class="item-1"></div>
    <div class="item-2"></div>
    <div class="item-2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <div class="item-block"></div>
    <div class="item-block"></div>
    <div class="item-block"></div>
    <div class="item-block"></div>
    <div class="item-block"></div>
    <div class="item-block"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```